# The method startManagingCursor(Cursor) is undefined

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working over database in an Android application . I am facing an issue with **startManagingCursor()** . I am trying to call this function in a non-activity class , but it is giving error that **The method startManagingCursor(Cursor) is undefined for the type DatabaseHelper** . I have visited  posts related to this question over stack overflow but didn't help .

```
Cursor cursorCircle = db.rawQuery(sqlCircle, null);

        if (cursorCircle.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                ---------------------
                code....
                ---------------------

            }while(cursorCircle.moveToNext());
            startManagingCursor(cursorCircle); //At this line it shows startManagingCursor() is undefined .
        }
```

Comment: It's a deprecated method in `Activity`. What are you trying achieve with a call to it?

Comment: Here I am trying to manage cursor's lifecycle over api 10 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using it, and start using [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), start [here](http://grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android)

But hey, if you want to continue to use it ,its an activity method,so pass an activity reference to your helper and then call it (see, it gets very entangled). But dont go on and create an activity via its constructor.

Comment: Please upvote the question as it can be helpfull for others too.